# PerfView's Metric/Interval greater than 1?

Tags: perfview

According to some PerfView material that I have seen/read online, I should dig into further CPU investigation if the **Metric/msec** is close to `1` (ex: 0.92), but I am seeing that in my case this value is `10.62`. What does this mean?

**Totals**

`Metric: 218,443.0
Count: 218,443.0 
First: 353.835
Last: 20,927.284
Last-First: 20,573.449
Metric/Interval: 10.62 
TimeBucket: 686.0
TotalProcs 12`

From `Last-First`, I can see that the profiling was done for 20,573 milliseconds, but the `Metric` is 218,443 samples. How come? Since PerfView takes one sample every 1 millisecond, I should not have seen this value greater than 20,573, right?

Is this count so high because the `Metric` here from ALL those 12 processors? If yes, so should I do the calculation like `(218443/12)/20573`, which gives me 0.88?